# Error thrown on List initialization

Tags: c#

Why would this yield a 'Method name expected' error?  (The part under new List[10] is squiggly underlined.)

```
List<int>[] whatever = new List<int>[10]();
```

Comment: "List initialization"? Are you trying to initialize a list of `int[10]` or an array of `List<int>`?

Answer (score 7):

```
List<int>[] whatever = new List<int>[10];
```

The syntax for initializing an array doesn't need parentheses. If you're trying to initialize a List with a starting capacity of 10, use:

```
List<int> whatever = new List<int>(10);
```

Comment: But it's a jagged array.  Still?

Comment: @user225626 yes, the first one could be defined as a jagged array. It is 10 Lists of integers. The second one is just a one dimensional list of integers.